# Getting id or src on click for appended images within div

Tags: javascript, html

I am having hard time trying to get either `id` or `src` of an image that I display using the following approach.

First, I have a div element:

```
<div id="FeedImages"; class="imageFeed"></div>
```

and then I loop through images that are stored within database like this:

```
temp2=0;
do{                     
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src",ImagePath);
            img.setAttribute("id",temp2);
            document.getElementById("FeedImages"+i).appendChild(img);
 
temp2++;
}while(temp<100);
```

This code works well in a sense that images are displayed as I wish. But I also want to have functionality where I could delete image, and for that I need to get `id` or `src` of any image. I tried just adding `onclick="test(this.id)";` into `div`, where function would just alert `clicked id`, but result always comes as `undefined`. There surely should be same way getting out `id=temp2`, but I find this complicated for all the wrong reasons. Could anyone share ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onclick attribute to the `img` as it's created.  You can pass the click event to the function that it calls and get the `id` from the `e.target` which is the click event target.

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute("src", "https://picsum.photos/200/300");
img.setAttribute("id", "tempId");
img.setAttribute("onclick","deleteImg(event)")
document.getElementById("FeedImages").appendChild(img);

function deleteImg(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id)
  // do something with the id
}
```

```html
<div id="FeedImages"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: Glad to help!  Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to wrap the image and the button in one div, add a envent listner to it and remove de parent node (div).

```js
    const ImagePath = setImageArray();
    let temp = 0;

    do {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", ImagePath[temp]);
        img.setAttribute("id", temp);
        const butn = document.createElement("button");
        butn.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.target.parentElement.remove();
        });
        butn.innerHTML = 'X';
        div.appendChild(img);
        div.appendChild(butn);
        document.getElementById("FeedImages").appendChild(div);


        temp++;
    } while (temp < 10);


//Setting array img source for demonstration purpose

    function setImageArray() {
        let arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arr.push(i.toString())
        }
        return arr
    }
```

```html
<div id="FeedImages" class="imageFeed"></div>
```